# Can't connect to Alcatel router (Dell XPS 13 9370) "Authorization supplicant timed out"

Tags: networking, wireless, dell

I've come across very strange problem trying to connect to my home wifi, which is provided by a T-Mobile Alcatel router, from Ubuntu (20.04) on my Dell XPS 13 9370.
Every time I try to connect it fails with the message:

> Authorization supplicant timed out

Removing the password protection from the network and clearing the saved network info had no effect.

Most notably:

- I've **no** issues connecting to any other WiFi-network.
- All other devices, aside from my laptop, can connect to the router just fine. (among them several linux devices)
- The problem has persisted even on a fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04
- None of the obvious quick-fixes, like restarting the network adapter, had any effect. *(Though I'm more than happy to try anything again if you have a suggestion)*

[The info](https://pastebin.com/9Hpc2BrN) of the wireless debugging as mentioned in an answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205).

*Any ideas for solutions or suggestions on how to more adequately debug the problem would be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: Look at the logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: Having the same problem here using Dell Latitude E7470 with an Alcatel router (Orange 4G network) in Egypt. All other devices(laptops/smart phones and tablets) are perfectly working including a smart TV. I’ve opened the router settings and by looking at the connected devices field i can see it increasing and decreasing from 6 back to 7 and then error is displayed on the laptop. My take on this, that is is somehow related to a specific network protocol/adapters in Dell laptops which is not compatible with Alcatel routers

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem, on Pop!_os with my Alcatel router (Orange 4G network) by installing iwd

install iwd

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install iwd
```

then ensure connection to the service by

```
sudo systemctl enable iwd.service
```

start the service

```
sudo systemctl start iwd.service
```

Next open /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and add

```
wifi.backend=iwd
```

to the [DEVICES] section.

References to this question here
[Problem with connection to wifi on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316988/problem-with-connection-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-20-04)