# Problem with connection to wifi on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.
Kernel: 5.4.0-65-generic

I have a problem to connect to my wifi adapter. Everytime i try to connect it shows these lines in /var/log/syslog.

```
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.3710] Config: added 'ssid' value 'HUAWEI-m33t-5G'
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.3710] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.3710] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.3710] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.3710] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.3710] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4061] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> authenticating
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4061] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: ready -> authenticating
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4120] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4120] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4277] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4278] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4435] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4435] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4647] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4648] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "HUAWEI-m33t-5G"
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4648] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4649] device (wlp1s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.4653] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 17 00:55:06 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519706.5089] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed unknown -> expire
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7427] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option dhcp_lease_time      => '259200'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7428] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.100.1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7428] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option expiry               => '1613778908'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7429] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option ip_address           => '192.168.100.16'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7429] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7429] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7429] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7429] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7429] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7430] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7430] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7430] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7430] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7430] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7431] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7431] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7431] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_routers    => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7431] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7431] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7431] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7432] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7432] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option routers              => '192.168.100.1'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7432] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7432] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed expire -> bound
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7491] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik dbus-daemon[1044]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.131' (uid=0 pid=5597 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7817] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7819] device (wlp1s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7824] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7914] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7916] policy: set 'HUAWEI-m33t-5G' (wlp1s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Feb 17 00:55:08 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519708.7922] device (wlp1s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Feb 17 00:55:09 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519709.4119] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Feb 17 00:55:09 ws16-silhavik whoopsie[1720]: [00:55:09] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/56
Feb 17 00:55:09 ws16-silhavik whoopsie[1720]: [00:55:09] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/56
Feb 17 00:55:09 ws16-silhavik whoopsie[1720]: [00:55:09] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/56
Feb 17 00:55:12 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519712.0706] dhcp6 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 17 00:55:12 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519712.0724] policy: set 'HUAWEI-m33t-5G' (wlp1s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Feb 17 00:55:12 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519712.1438] dhcp6 (wlp1s0): option dhcp6_name_servers   => 'fe80::1'
Feb 17 00:55:12 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519712.1439] dhcp6 (wlp1s0): state changed unknown -> bound
**Feb 17 00:55:17 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <warn>  [1613519717.8735] sup-iface[0x55e24cba1930,wlp1s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)**
Feb 17 00:55:17 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519717.8952] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Feb 17 00:55:17 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519717.8953] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Feb 17 00:55:17 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519717.9788] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb 17 00:55:17 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519717.9789] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb 17 00:55:22 ws16-silhavik systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <warn>  [1613519733.0658] device (wlp1s0): link timed out.
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519733.0692] device (wlp1s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519733.0698] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <warn>  [1613519733.0705] device (wlp1s0): Activation: failed for connection 'HUAWEI-m33t-5G'
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519733.0712] device (wlp1s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik dbus-daemon[1044]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.131' (uid=0 pid=5597 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
**Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop[2687]: "No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties” on object at path** /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/56"
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519733.1068] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519733.1068] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed bound -> done
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519733.1070] dhcp6 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 17 00:55:33 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519733.1070] dhcp6 (wlp1s0): state changed bound -> done
Feb 17 00:55:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519737.1337] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Feb 17 00:55:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[5597]: <info>  [1613519737.1341] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
```

I think that could be a problem with some interface or something else. It works properly from any other devices (iPhones, mac) but the only problem is with my Dell with Ubuntu 20.04.

I don't know if it is related but every time I tried to connect to wifi other devices lost connection for a couple of minutes. It looks like my attempt restarts the wifi adapter. The same thing happened when I tried wired connection.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The added information about how other devices **can** connect to the wireless access point however your (Dell) with Ubuntu **cannot** was very helpful. This could be because of a couple reasons however: One could be that the Channel is in heavy use for the Network you want to connect on, the other would be faulty /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf using (configured as) wpa-supplicant instead of iwd. 
 
*1.* The SSID you are trying to connect to has too many users on that particular channel setup and there is interference from other wireless access points.
 You can find this out by typing: 
`sudo nmcli dev wifi list`
This will allow you to observe set channel of various networks and signal strength.
*2.* For whatever reason the Network-Manager on your setup could not do well with wpa-supplicant and instead needs iwd instead.
 First install iwd with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install iwd`
 then ensure connection to the service by 
`sudo systemctl enable iwd.service`
`sudo systemctl start iwd.service`
 Next open `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and add `wifi.backend=iwd` to the *[DEVICES]* section.
 After a reboot this will yield a positive connection if all changes were saved. If not there could also be some Network-Manager parameter that needs to be modified in that same file that prevents connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will post the result later.

Comment: Upon further research into backend iwd service, it seems to have selectiveness when it comes to using a band. If the signal strength of 2.4GHz is stronger than 5GHz, then it will connect to 2.4GHz, maybe restart iwd.service with "sudo systemctl restart iwd" and boot again to connect to 5GHz.... at least step in right direction. It could also be the SSID or even BSSID addresses and how the back end selects the access point.

Comment: I'm also interested in the config error in your updated answer... "No secrets" for the 5GHz.  [config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')] Could it be possible that you are using open WIFI or the same password applies for both bands? There is a program you can use with network manager to interact with set connections called "nmtui", could you possibly reset the connection from there? You can edit automatic connections with nmtui.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed the issue by half. Now, I am able to connect to wifi via 2G network, but 5G network still doesn't work.

The same issue with restarting wifi adapter (wifi networks 2G, 5G are unavailable for a couple of minutes) when plugin ethernet or try 5G network.

I think it's no problem with high traffic, as well. I tested the issue during the night when nobody has been connected and it is our home network.

There is log after succesfull connect to 2G and attempt for switch to 5G.

```
Feb 18 02:08:19 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610499.3353] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wireless-enabled" pid=2728 uid=1000 result="success"
Feb 18 02:08:19 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610499.3409] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now enabled by radio killswitch
Feb 18 02:08:19 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610499.5875] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is disconnected
Feb 18 02:08:19 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610499.5878] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:20 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610500.8431] policy: auto-activating connection 'HUAWEI-m33t-2G' (6f9081fe-6a97-4a52-a069-10bd0964b0ab)
Feb 18 02:08:20 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610500.8440] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'HUAWEI-m33t-2G' (6f9081fe-6a97-4a52-a069-10bd0964b0ab)
Feb 18 02:08:20 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610500.8478] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:20 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610500.8488] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Feb 18 02:08:20 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610500.8499] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:20 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610500.8664] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is connecting
Feb 18 02:08:20 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610500.9328] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to 'HUAWEI-m33t-2G'.
Feb 18 02:08:20 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610500.9331] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is connected
Feb 18 02:08:20 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610500.9332] device (wlan0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:20 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610500.9336] dhcp4 (wlan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0501] dhcp4 (wlan0): option dhcp_lease_time      => '259200'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0501] dhcp4 (wlan0): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.100.1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option expiry               => '1613869700'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option ip_address           => '192.168.100.16'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_routers    => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0502] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0503] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0503] dhcp4 (wlan0): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0503] dhcp4 (wlan0): option routers              => '192.168.100.1'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0503] dhcp4 (wlan0): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0503] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed unknown -> bound
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0515] device (wlan0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0546] device (wlan0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0548] device (wlan0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0551] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0558] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0559] policy: set 'HUAWEI-m33t-2G' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.0563] device (wlan0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610501.3788] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik whoopsie[1807]: [02:08:21] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/13
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik whoopsie[1807]: [02:08:21] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/13
Feb 18 02:08:21 ws16-silhavik whoopsie[1807]: [02:08:21] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/13
Feb 18 02:08:22 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610502.0247] dhcp6 (wlan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 18 02:08:22 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610502.0253] policy: set 'HUAWEI-m33t-2G' (wlan0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Feb 18 02:08:22 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610502.0506] dhcp6 (wlan0): option dhcp6_name_servers   => 'fe80::1'
Feb 18 02:08:22 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610502.0506] dhcp6 (wlan0): state changed unknown -> bound
Feb 18 02:08:31 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610511.9288] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is disconnected
Feb 18 02:08:31 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610511.9289] device (wlan0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:31 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <warn>  [1613610511.9300] device (wlan0): Activation: failed for connection 'HUAWEI-m33t-2G'
Feb 18 02:08:31 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610511.9318] device (wlan0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:31 ws16-silhavik org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop[3007]: "No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties” on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/13"
Feb 18 02:08:31 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610511.9745] dhcp4 (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 18 02:08:31 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610511.9745] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed bound -> done
Feb 18 02:08:31 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610511.9748] dhcp6 (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 18 02:08:31 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610511.9748] dhcp6 (wlan0): state changed bound -> done
Feb 18 02:08:31 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610511.9851] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Feb 18 02:08:36 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610516.8269] policy: auto-activating connection 'HUAWEI-m33t-2G' (6f9081fe-6a97-4a52-a069-10bd0964b0ab)
Feb 18 02:08:36 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610516.8330] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'HUAWEI-m33t-2G' (6f9081fe-6a97-4a52-a069-10bd0964b0ab)
Feb 18 02:08:36 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610516.8332] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:36 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610516.8337] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Feb 18 02:08:36 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610516.8343] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.0280] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is connecting
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <error> [1613610517.0574] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) Network.Connect failed: GDBus.Error:net.connman.iwd.Failed: Operation failed
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.0580] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is disconnected
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.0582] device (wlan0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.0590] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <warn>  [1613610517.0608] device (wlan0): Activation: failed for connection 'HUAWEI-m33t-2G'
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.0614] device (wlan0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop[3007]: "No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties” on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/14"
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.4854] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'HUAWEI-m33t-5G' (2a48419e-6fea-4644-b89f-d04a820c38b4)
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.4854] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="2a48419e-6fea-4644-b89f-d04a820c38b4" name="HUAWEI-m33t-5G" pid=2728 uid=1000 result="success"
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.4855] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.4858] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.4861] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.4963] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is connecting
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <error> [1613610517.6850] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) Network.Connect failed: GDBus.Error:net.connman.iwd.Failed: Operation failed
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.6852] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is disconnected
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.6853] device (wlan0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.6855] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <warn>  [1613610517.6861] device (wlan0): Activation: failed for connection 'HUAWEI-m33t-5G'
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik NetworkManager[1076]: <info>  [1613610517.6862] device (wlan0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 02:08:37 ws16-silhavik org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop[3007]: "No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties” on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/15"
Feb 18 02:08:41 ws16-silhavik systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with a cloned Mint 20.3 machine.  It disconnects from the wifi when it's inactive for 10 minutes or so.  I had changed the hostname and the ssh keys, but changing the machine-id seemed to resolve the problem.  It's described here: http://ichimusai.org/after-cloning-a-ubuntu-22-04-server/

```
sudo rm /etc/machine-id 
sudo systemd-machine-id-setup
```