# How do I get a wireless network to come up when it stays DOWN after telling it to come up?

Tags: wireless, 20.04

`PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"`

Got a wireless chip in my HTPC and I can't get it to connect to the wireless in the house (2 android phones, 2 macs and 1 windows machine have no issues). Ubuntu 20. I bought this machine years ago but it's always had a wired connection. In the new house a wired connection means drilling and time in the crawlspace, so I'd like to get the wifi working. The onboard wireless is listed as "802.11AC + Bluetooth V4.0 or 802.11 BGN" in the machine specs. I am currently using a wired connection but that means a cable running across the floor.

The issue is that I can't get the wifi to come up at all. There is a very detailed wifi connection troubleshooter on this site. I've done many of the steps from it with no luck. Sorry, I can't find the link in my history. I think the issue I ran into with that troubleshooter was that my wifi list has no wifi listed:

```
$ nmcli dev wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
$
```

Onboard chip info:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
```

Network configs:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
```

I think the issue is that the wifi protocol won't come up:

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: ...omitted
2: enp2s0: ...omitted
3: wlp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:e6:ad:da:28:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ sudo ip link set wlp3s0 up

$ ip link show | grep wlp
3: wlp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
```

Still down.

Looking at this [question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199565/interface-doesnt-go-up-with-ip-link-set-interface-up) they suggest using `killall dhcpcd` but I think that might kill my connection (I'm using ssh as this is a HTPC and keyboard access is an issue). They also suggested looking at journalctl, but I don't see anything there.

```
$ journalctl -xe | grep -A 5 wlp
Sep 04 07:43:29 media-cube sudo[34355]:    media : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/media ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/ifconfig wlp3s0 up
Sep 04 07:43:29 media-cube sudo[34355]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by media(uid=0)
Sep 04 07:43:29 media-cube sudo[34355]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 04 07:45:25 media-cube sudo[34433]:    media : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/media ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/ip link set wlp3s0 up
Sep 04 07:45:25 media-cube sudo[34433]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by media(uid=0)
Sep 04 07:45:25 media-cube sudo[34433]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 04 07:48:40 media-cube sudo[34554]:    media : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/media ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/ip link set wlp3s0 up
Sep 04 07:48:40 media-cube sudo[34554]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by media(uid=0)
Sep 04 07:48:40 media-cube sudo[34554]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

`rfkill list all` doesn't show any hard or soft blocks.

After hashing on this problem for a while I took a guess that the chip was defective so I bought a wifi adapter (edimax EW-7822UAC). Can't get it working either. I've installed the drivers but Ubuntu doesn't seem to see it, even after a reboot. The [Ubuntu troubleshooter](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-device-drivers.html.en) stops at "make sure your have working drivers installed", so I'm not sure where to go next.

Speed is important here, as this is a media player, so I suspect I will need to get the external adapter going but using onboard would be simpler and cheaper.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: `device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'ex` ?

Comment: Message in the logs about "reason 'supplicant-available'". Maybe I need to change over to iwd? https://askubuntu.com/a/1317005/35158

Comment: here I put the journal output up on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/2HffpUxZ

Comment: Please edit your question to show: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: I'm told /etc/network/interfaces is deprecated, you sure that's the right way to go? I'll get that info for you, hold on

Comment: *interfaces* is indeed deprecated. I just wanted to be certain that is was correctly missing. How about: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: here you go https://pastebin.com/bXxynng1

Comment: " I've installed the drivers but Ubuntu doesn't seem to see it, even after a reboot." What driver did you install? With it plugged in, may we see: `lsusb` The built-in Intel is, so far, a mystery. I see nothing wrong and fixable, except it just won't work.

Comment: Chipset is an Intel 3160. Driver and instructions [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html). They amount to "copy the files into lib/firmware". The file is "iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode" -- which I have confirmed is in lib/firmware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129273/discussion-between-chili555-and-jcollum).

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20. What version are you running?

Comment: @David please see first line of the post

Comment: @chili555 solved https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/668879/29679